# Change a forEach() method to a For Loop to use with IntersectionObserver - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, intersection-observer

I have the following IntersectionObserver code that is working as a scroll trigger for animations on a site that all works OK.

However, I would like to switch the forEach() method that works as the call for the IntersectionObserver to a for loop, but I can't get this to work.

I'm sure that this can be done, but it's driving me a bit crazy.

The reason for wanting this is because I'm using a polyfill so that IntersectionObserver works in older versions of IE and Edge, but of course the forEach() method doesn't work in these browsers.

I've commented out my attempt at the loop at the bottom of the code.

Any help would be amazing.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/xJaZay

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
var iO = "IntersectionObserver" in window; /* true if supported */
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  
if (iO) {
  const config = {
    root: null, // sets the framing element to the viewport
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: .5
  };
    
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function(item) {
      
      if (item.intersectionRatio > .5) {
        
        item.target.classList.add("active");

      } else {
        item.target.classList.remove("active");
      }
      
    });
    
  }, config);

  box.forEach(function(item){
    observer.observe(item);
  });

  // for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  // observer[i].observe(item);
  // }
  
} // end of if(iO)
  
}); // end of load event
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 280vh;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s all;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#box1{
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.active {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: You could also just polyfill `forEach` as well - or convert `box` to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one observer but you're applying an index on it.  As you're iterating over the boxes, your index accessor should be on box.

```
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    observer.observe(box[i]);
}
```

This should work, it's untested though.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I can't believe some low-life down-voted the question

Comment: Your welcome! For the record, I don't see any downvotes on the question though - perhaps it was a mistake.

Comment: Yes it was on 1 vote, then a drive-by happened. Anyway, more importantly I got an answer :)

Comment: Added up vote. Reasonable question to ask if stuck, imho. It helped me find an answer to something. And thanks @Phil Cooper